# How do I wire two receptacles to a switch when the switch is at the beginning of the run?

Tags: receptacle

I want to have two receptacles controlled by a switch and the switch is at the beginning of the run. How do I wire that?

Comment: Does "the run" consist solely of one switch followed by two receptacles, or are there other devices on "the run"?

Comment: Just the two receptacles

Comment: And the one switch, sorry

Comment: Do you want all 4 outlets to be switched, or just one outlet of each pair switched?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a switch followed by two receptacles, you bring in always-hot, neutral, and ground (connects to the box first, if using a steel box, and we do like those better) to the switch, connect always-hot to one terminal on the switch, and send out switched hot connected to the other terminal on the switch, neutral (joined to incoming neutral) and ground (joined to incoming ground) to the receptacles to be switched, which are wired as usual since you have not specified any oddities like half-switching them or other receptacles not to be switched after them.

If the circuit breaker is 15A, the switch can be rated for 15A and the wire can be 14 AWG. If the circuit breaker is 20A, the switch must be rated for 20A, (which will require careful shopping) and the wire must be 12AWG (or larger, but there's generally no reason to do that.)

Most people would do this with NM/B cable such as 14/2 or 12/2 - there's no need for /3 cable here as described so far. *I'm the oddball doing conduit or MC even though my local code does not require it. I have higher standards; and I know how long it takes the fire department to show up to a rural location. Prevention is worth the hassle, to me*

Comment: I will give that a try. Thank you

Comment: FYI, I just did a quick search to verify, you **can** use 15A switches for hardwired <15A loads on 20A circuits. Where you must use 20A switches is for receptacles on 20A circuits. But since most people use most switches for hardwired lighting, there are an awful lot of switches that are only 15A rated.

Comment: Good to know, but this question *is* about receptacles, so the rarer 20A switch must be found if it's a 20A breaker.